# what's the effect on this page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just hoping to find out what the effect is on this page:

http://www.spacho.com/

I would like to do something similar.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly you want from that page?.

Comment: Which effect? That page seems to have several.

Answer (score 2):

It's called paralax scrolling. You can find a lot of tutorials and plugins online to help you create a similar effect.